# How can I avoid a 302 for Fetch as Google?

Tags: seo, http-redirect

My web application is very similar to [notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc) which redirects to a randomly generated URL upon access, e.g. `http://myapp.com/roTr94h4Gd`. (Please note that notepad.cc is not my site.)

Probably because of this redirect feature, when I do "fetch as Gogle" in the Google Webmaster tools, I get a 302 and no html content. Not even a `<html></html>` tag.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.4.1
Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2013 04:37:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=vp99q5e5t5810e3bnnnvi6sfo2; expires=Thu, 03-Oct-2013 04:37:37 GMT; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /roTr94h4Gd
```

How should I avoid 302 in this case? I suppose I could modify my site to prevent the redirect, but it is a necessary feature of my web app to generate a random URL on each access. This means that bots may index `http://myapp.com/xxxxx` where `xxxxx` is different each time. I believe this does not help to promote my site in search engines.

I could add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag into my index page so that I can return a page that is created specifically for bots. However, I suspect that this is a dangerous approach because my site may be flagged as using a black hat approach.

Could someone tell me a good suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the server code to send status 200 instead of 302. In .Net could be

Response.StatusCode = 200;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx

Comment: But that only returns 200 and won't return the html content of my site, correct?

Comment: you can redirect to your desired url and force the status on 200, as you telling the server exactly which status to send. I hope it helps :-)

Comment: I tried to return 200 status code, but it didn't work. I use PHP. The index page redirects to itself after generating some random string and it is still returning "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily". When I fetch as a Bingbot, the result said "Status:  Redirection limit reached.". Does this mean anything?